# Can I transform arithmetic operators to their equivalent function calls?

Tags: replacement, input-forms

I'm looking for something like "complete `InputForm`" which works for the basic arithmetic operators

I have a simple expression like `a+b*c-d`

I need to transform it to `Subtract[Plus[a, Times[b, c]], d]` or equivalent (since the order of + and - is not important)

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done by

```
FullForm[a + b*c - d]
```

> `Plus[a,Times[b,c],Times[-1,d]]`